# Publish Tab not visible

Tags: publishing-site, publishing-page

I have a Sharepoint Portal with "Sharepoint Server Publishing" feature activated at site collection level. I have few pages in subsite and some page have "Page" and "publish" tabs and for some pages I only get Site Actions menu. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, pages created in site/SitePages wont have the Publishing tab because versioning on these Library types are set to "Create major versions" . Major versions do not require Publishing as it creates a new major version when you check-in, save.

Pages created in site/Pages will have the publishing because that Library type is set to create "major and minor (draft) versions".

Anyways, to fix the issue for pages/items created in SitePages, go to the Library Settings > Versioning Settings > Select "Create major and minor(draft) versions.

Go back to any page in that library and you'll now find the Publishing tab.

Comment: You also need to activate the site-level counterpart of the Publishing Infrastructure feature at each site under your site collection

Comment: Hi Fox, I checked the library settings and "create major and minor (draft) versions" is already selected. If a page is not yet published then I get the Page and Publish tab enabled. If n content on the page is published(using the publish tab) then after publishing, page and publish tab is not visible. Does it mean once publishing I cant edit the content again?

Comment: Hi Louis, its already activated.

Comment: I suspect the publish tab will come back once you check out the page/item.

Comment: Thanks Fox,if I edit the page then I get the page and publish tab.